# How Can I search particular one record in duration of 2 date in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, eloquent

In my leave request page I have one search bar on leave duration column, In leave duration column there are to dates, first is start date of leave and 2nd is end date of leave.

I wanna do that, In search bar if i write a date between those to date than i get output of that record.
My database is mongodb

leavedate is variable with that i am finding records.

Here Is my controller file code

```
 public function listOfLeave(Request $request)
    {


        $allLeaves = null;
        if (
            !empty($request->input('name')) || 
            !empty($request->input('leaveType')) ||
            !empty($request->input('leaveDate')) ||
            !empty($request->input('appliedDate')) || 
            !empty($request->input('status'))       
        )
        {
            $flg = false; 

            if (!empty($request->input('name')))
            {
                $flg = true; 
                $allLeaves=LeaveManagement::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('name')}%");
            }

            if (!empty($request->input('leaveType')))
            {
                if($flg)
                {
                    $allLeaves=$allLeaves->orWhere('type', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('leaveType')}%");
                }
                else 
                {
                    $allLeaves=LeaveManagement::where('type', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('leaveType')}%");
                }
            }



            if (!empty($request->input('leaveDate'))) 
            {
                if ($flg) 
                {
                    $allLeaves = $allLeaves->orWhere('end', '>=', $request->input('leaveDate'))
                                            ->orWhere('start', '<=', $request->input('leaveDate'));
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $allLeaves = LeaveManagement::where('end', '>=', $request->input('leaveDate'));
                }
            }

            if (!empty($request->input('appliedDate')))
            {
                if($flg)
                {
                    $allLeaves=$allLeaves->orWhere('start', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('appliedDate')}%");
                }
                else 
                {
                    $allLeaves=LeaveManagement::where('start', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('appliedDate')}%");
                }
            }

            if (!empty($request->input('status')))
            {
                if($flg)
                {
                    $allLeaves=$allLeaves->orWhere('status', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('status')}%");
                }
                else 
                {
                    $allLeaves=LeaveManagement::where('status', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('status')}%");
                }
            }

            $allLeaves = $allLeaves ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
                                    ->orderBy('type', 'ASC')
                                    ->orderBy('start', 'ASC')
                                    ->orderBy('start', 'ASC')
                                    ->orderBy('status', 'ASC')
                                    ->paginate(25);

            return view('pages.newleaverequest')->with(['allLeaves'=>$allLeaves]);  
        }
        else 
        {
            $allLeaves=LeaveManagement::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->paginate(25);  
        }

        $allLeaves->appends(array('name'=>Input::get('name')));

        return view('pages.newleaverequest', compact('allLeaves'));

    }
```

Here Is My View File

```
<form action="{{ route('manage_leave') }}" method="GET" role="search">
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">

  <input type="text" class="form-control " id="search1" name="name" placeholder="Employee Name">                                    
  <select class="custom-select form-control col-md-2" id="search5" name="leaveType">
     <option value="">Leave Type</option>
     <option value="casual">Casual Leave</option>
     <option value="medical">Medical Leave</option>
     <option value="early">Early Leave</option>
</select>

   <input type="date" class="form-control " id="search3" name="leaveDate" placeholder="Leave Date">
   <input type="date" class="form-control " id="search4" name="appliedDate" placeholder="Applied Date">
   <select class="custom-select form-control col-md-2" id="search5" name="status">
   <option value="">Status</option>
   <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
   <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
   <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
</select>
&emsp;&emsp;
<button class="btn btn-info" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search "></i></button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
  @if(isset($allLeaves))
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                                    <th>Leave Type</th>
                                    <th>Leave Duration</th>
                                    <th>Applied On</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @if($allLeaves != null)
                                @foreach($allLeaves as $leave)
                                <tr>
                                    <td> {{ $leave->name }} </td>
                                    <td> {{ $leave->type }} </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($leave->start)) }} To
                                        {{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($leave->end)) }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td> {{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($leave->start)) }} </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @if($leave['status']=='Pending')
                                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning" style="color:white;font-size: 90%;font-weight:bold;">Pending</span>
                                        @elseif($leave['status']=='Approved')
                                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success" style="color:white;font-size: 90%;font-weight:bold;">Approved</span>
                                        @else
                                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger" style="color:white;font-size: 90%;font-weight:bold;">Rejected</span>
                                        @endif
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="{{route('handle_leave', $leave->id)}}" class="btn btn-info text-white">Details</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                                @endif
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div>
                            {{ $allLeaves->render() }}
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: In which variable you're posting your date? Also from which fields do you want to search that specific date is there between them?

Comment: **<input type="date" class="form-control " id="search3" name="leaveDate" placeholder="Leave Date">**
Here is my search bar
In leaveDate I am posting date

Comment: You're not getting my question I think. If I want to check ```leaveDate``` you've provided is between a range or not, then for that range which fields I have to look after? In short, which  database field do I use to compare if your date lies between?

Comment: Owk I am sorry in database that fields names are **startDate** &  **endDate**

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the code block of your function:

```
if (!empty($request->input('leaveDate'))) 
{
    if ($flg) 
    {
        $allLeaves = $allLeaves->orWhere(function($query) use ($request){
            $query->whereDate('end', '>=', $request->input('leaveDate'))
                ->whereDate('start', '<=', $request->input('leaveDate'));
        });
    } 
    else 
    {
        $allLeaves = LeaveManagement::where('end', '>=', $request->input('leaveDate'));
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works?

Comment: It's working but there is one problem https://ibb.co/mCdb7x3

See if i search record between **26-05-2019 To 27-05-2019** it will give me record of 4th month too

Comment: I have updated where condition of my answer. Just place it and check it.

Comment: Nope same issue still,
I have 2 records **26-05-2019 To 27-05-2019** and **06-05-2019 To 18-05-2019**
If I search **07-05-2019** than it have to give me only 2nd record, this is give me both

Comment: OK. I want to see what you've passed in your ```$request``` variable. Can you just write ```print_r($request->all()); exit;``` on the top of your method and post here the result?

Comment: It disaply this **Array ( )**

Comment: If it is a blank array then you're not posting any values so that it is returning all records to you. Also, if you're posing only ```leaveDate``` then condition will be like where start is >= leaveDate and end <= leaveDate and that will return you only records that are of a specific date, not the date range. So I think there is some confusion in the fields you are looking into.

Comment: In search bar Get will be suitable or Post method??? because I wrote get method in form

Comment: The request method (whether GET or POST) should be matched with the Route you've created for. Check your request using inspector in browser what you're posting with the request and on laravel you're able to receive the same or not?

Comment: in route I wrote Get method too

Comment: Then please check why you're not able to get the request variable leaveDate ?

Comment: OK. Can you post the codes using which you're making Get Request and Route?

Comment: In web.php file this is the Route
**Route::get('manage-leave', 'LeaveManagementController@listOfLeave')->name('manage_leave');**

Comment: Can you change your Route to ```Route::post('manage-leave', 'LeaveManagementController@listOfLeave')->name('manage_leave');``` and Form method to POST using ```<form action="{{ route('manage_leave') }}" method="POST" role="search">``` and then try ```print_r($request->all());exit;``` on the top of ```listOfLeave``` method? Let us see what it prints.

Comment: that gives this error **Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message**

Comment: OK. Set ```<form action="{{ route('manage-leave') }}" method="POST" role="search">``` and ```Route::post('manage-leave', 'LeaveManagementController@listOfLeave');```   then try ```print_r($request->all());exit;```

Comment: Nope still same error instead of route i tried url too, this is like index file so i think GET will be use instead of POST

Comment: OK.. Anyhow, try getting the request variables first.Because once you get the input then only we will be able to build up the query to get the desired record.